# How to increase polling time in KCL 2.x incase of multi-stream?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-client

I want to poll data after every 5minute, instead of default time. I am seeing there is a parameter idleTImeBetweenReadInMillis which says it is polling time. But when I am setting it to 5minute, it is not working. So, is there any other parameter to override or it is not possible to increase poll time. I have gone through the documentation of KCL, but did not found any solution. Is there any way to implement this?